# Erro ao tentar conectar com outro servidor Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

Estou tentando enviar mensagem para uma outra máquina na minha rede que já possui o rabbitmq instalado.

O seguinte erro ocorre:

> Messagem de erro: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Ao acessar essa máquina via web browser funciona corretamente. Então sei que o problema não está na minha rede e nem no rabbit mq

Abaixo o codigo que estou usando

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "[ip da máquina aqui]",
            Port = 15672,
            UserName = "meu usuario",
            Password = "minha senha"
        };
        try
        {
            using (var conexao = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var canal = conexao.CreateModel())
                {
                    canal.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                    string mensagem = args[0];
                    var corpo = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mensagem);

                    canal.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: corpo);
                    Console.WriteLine("[x] Sent {0}", mensagem);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Pressione [enter] tecla para sair");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Messagem de erro: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução para o meu problema.
Era necessário alterar a porta.

```
   Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
```

Então o meu código de conexão ficou dessa forma:

```
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
    {
        HostName = "[ip da máquina aqui]",
        Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
        UserName = "meu usuario",
        Password = "minha senha"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre da confusão entre as portas utilizadas pelo RabbitMQ. O serviço de mensageria corretipicamente na porta `5672`. Entretanto, o plugin de administração corre na porta `15672`.

Pelo descrito na perguta, os testes foram feitos pela interface web, que acessa então ao painel administrativo na porta `15672`.

A porta que as aplicações devem usar para se conectar ao RabbitMQ é a `5672`.